# Scala warning without line number

Tags: scala

I am seeing a few of these warnings in my build:

```
At the end of the day, could not inline @inline-marked method ->$extension
```

These are produced by using operator `->` in `Map` in scala 2.10 (I can't move to scala 2.12 right now).

but no line number is provided. Is there a scala compiler option I need to turn on to get line number details?

Comment: Are you using the `@inline` annotation?

Comment: Operator `->` on `Map` does in 2.10.

Comment: Hmm.. do you have `-Yinline-warnings` explicitly enabled? I don't think it will get the line number.

Comment: I'm using scala plugin in gradle. Let me see...